# unable to open webpage after user-data-dir argument is added to options

Tags: python, selenium

I added a user-data-dir argument to my webdriver options to run selenium through my personal chrome profile. The code opens chrome in the appropriate chrome profile but it is not able to go to "http://www.python.org". The code works perfectly without adding the user-data-dir argument.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install() #using latest chromedriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C://Users/Name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data") #Path to chrome profile

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the profile path like below:

```
# path of the chrome profile's parent directory
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
# name of the directory
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")   # you can change this directory name, if you want to use some other directory
```

Before executing the above code, close all of Chrome browser windows and chromedriver.exe.